# Where does "apt list" search?

Tags: apt, search

`apt list` can list all packages available, does `apt` search in some database or file in some directory? `apt list --installed` can list all installed packages, where does `apt` search then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt list` uses the information available in `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages` (corresponding to repositories in its configuration) and the relevant `_Translation` files.

Installed packages are tracked in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

To see which files are used on your system, run

```
strace -e openat apt list > /dev/null
```

and

```
strace -e openat apt list --installed > /dev/null
```